# How to fetch data to train my neural network model in Kaggle?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, kaggle

I am trying to build a convolution neural network which classifies between cats and dogs,to train that network I am using Kaggle as a tool ,I have uploaded all the data sets consisting of 8000 training set and 2000 testing set.

Problem is how to fetch the data from the input folder? 
Screenshot is in the below link.

[image: Click here to view image]

This is the error which I am getting.

[image: Click here to view image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: predictive spelling is wrong...but even if corrected it still it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may have misspelled your actual folder name "predictive" and instead have spelled it "predective" in the code.

-Lando

Comment: You can use [tab complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion) in kernels; I find it helps me with spelling mistakes (I'm dyslexic, so it's a big problem for me).